How do I map() all images in a folder? | React.js and Vite
I need to map through all images in a folder in the public directory, and I was following this post  to try to do that but I'm getting this error
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined at GalleryPage.jsx:8:16
Here is my code
const images = require.context("/_fairImages", true);
const imageList = images.keys().map((image) => images(image));

function GalleryPage() { 
  return (
    <div className="galleryPage_v2">
      <div className="galleryWrapper">
        {imageList.map((image, index) => (
          <img src={image.default} alt="" className="galleryImg" />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}




You can't list directory contents from inside the browser.

Since you are using Vite you can try import.meta.glob it is similar to Webpack's require.context
// Dynamically import all images in the _fairImages folder
const images = import.meta.glob('/public/_fairImages/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,svg}', { eager: true });

function GalleryPage() {
  const imageList = Object.values(images).map((image, index) => (
    <img key={index} src={image.default} alt={`Image ${index + 1}`} className="galleryImg" />
  ));

  return (
    <div className="galleryPage_v2">
      <div className="galleryWrapper">
        {imageList}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


Yup this worked, thank you so much!!

Well the one time that i needed to do something like this i used the following approach: 
I created an array of image names from the folder that contained the images.
Here is how you can do it:
const importAll = (r) => {
    let images = {};
    r.keys().map((item, index) => { images[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
    return images;
  };
  
  const images = importAll(require.context('./images', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/))

Here is what I am doing:

require.context provides all the file paths that match the pattern (regex) provided
false in importAll function indivcates weather to include subdirectories or Not
Regex for checking files with image extensions

Now that I have the names of images, i can simply iterate over the:
<div className="image-gallery">
        {Object.keys(images).map((imageName, index) => (
          <img key={index} src={images[imageName]} alt={imageName} />
        ))}
</div>


Since I'm using Vite I cant use require.context, but I'm glad you explained what false and /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/ does, I didnt know that. So thank you so much

require.context needs to be interpreted by your bundler, not the runtime.
Are you using webpack to bundle your code before running it in the browser?
https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext

Oh ok, I didnt know that about require.context.
No I'm not using webpack, I'm actually using Vite
